# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar una sesión en Django luego de un tiempo de inactividad?

Tags: python, django, web

Tengo una app en Django y necesito que luego de determinado tiempo de inactividad la sesión del admin se cierre, ya utilicé el "`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True`" para que la sesión se cierre si el navegador cierra, y `"SESSION_COOKIE_AGE"` pero ese cierra la sesión pasado el tiempo aun cuando hay actividad. ¿hay alguna forma de cerrar la sesión por inactividad?

Answer (score 1):

Depende a que se defina en tu modelo de negocio como "actividad", si actividad se refiere estar mandando peticiones de una u otra manera entonces sí. El objeto session que viene en el request de Django te sirve para eso, lo puedes haces es un [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/topics/http/middleware/), lo que el middleware se encarga recibir todos los requests.

Dentro del objeto request tienes la "session", donde puedes poner un tiempo de expiración. (Al session, le puedes agregar lo que gustes y se mantendrá en la sesión del usuario)

```
if request.session['exp_time'] < datetime.now():
    logout()
    # matar la sesión.
else:
   # actualiza el exp_time en la sesión. 
   request.session['exp_time'] = new_expiration()
```

Con eso cada que se haga una petición esta pasara por tu middleware y podrás verificar la expiración.

Otra opción, puedes usar javascript y AJAX para estar revisado algún vista de Django y si la vista regresa que ya paso el tiempo de expiración con el mismo javascript rediriges el usuario a pantalla de cierre de sesión.